# How to disable touchpad in Loki beta?

Tags: settings, touchpad, release-loki

I want to disable the touchpad manually in the settings dialog. In freya, there was a switch to disable the touchpad. In loki it seesm this switch is not there anymore. Is there another place where I can disable the touchpad via the GUI (not using the command line)?

Best regards

Comment: fallback to synaptics drivers and you should get more options. see http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7545/trackpad-randomly-freezes/7562

Answer (score 3):

On elementary OS Loki you can't disable the touchpad from System Settings, you have to install `dconf-editor`, open it and go to `org->gnome->desktop->peripherals->touchpad` there on `send-events` select `disable` or `disable-on-external-mouse`, with that you disable the touchpad.